Ensuring Cart Item Expiration and Price Accuracy in PayPal Integration
I manage a nonprofit organization's website that integrates with PayPal for event pass purchases. I've noticed that buyers can keep older passes or items in their cart for extended periods and are able to purchase them even after we've altered the price or removed the item from PayPal. I'm interested in learning if there is an option to set cart item expirations, ensuring that the latest price is always applied or preventing users from purchasing items that have been removed.

Presumably you are using old PayPal Payment Standard buttons such as "add to cart", which are deprecated and no longer supported.
PayPal advises switching to a currently-supported integration, such as

New Pay links and buttons, which do not currently support cart functionality, but may in the future
The current standard checkout, which requires a backend to create and capture the order using server-side code
A pre-integrated cart product from some third party or open source -- see PayPal's partner directory for a place to start, but there are many others

